# How can I use CAS with a Javascript Client that will be hosted as well as used in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cross-domain, single-sign-on, cas

I am writing a Phonegap application that needs to be able to call remote webservices that are secured by CAS. The application will also be hosted on our webfarm (minus the hardware specific parts) as a mobile web site.

Our CAS server is hosted by server1 and our webservices are hosted on server2. The mobile web site is hosted on server2.

Any calls I make from Javascript get a cross-domain error. I realize this isn't an issue for the phone, but it would be nice to avoid it due to development being so much easier when running on the desktop.

Currently, I have a working setup that consists of the following:

1. Javascript calls a server-side script on server2 over https, including the username and password in the header.
2. The script calls CAS' RESTful api and gets a ticket granting cookie. The script creates a Set-Cookie header in the response or it reports back with a login error.
3. Javascript gets the response and creates the cookie (though this cookie is undetectable in Phonegap (nothing in document.cookie), even though it's getting passed around).
4. Javascript then calls a server-side script which calls a webservice for it, passing the cookie with the request (I had to manually insert the cookie into the request header, even though it automatically was passed in the request from javascript).
5. The server-side script sends the results to javascript.

Is there a better way to do this? I've seen mention of proxy tickets in CAS, but cannot find enough information to know whether it's what I need or how to use them.

Thank you.